# Juntar objetos dentro de coleção de objetos diferentes

Tags: java, array

Como faço para "juntar" ou concatenar um objeto dentro de uma coleção de objetos diferentes? Já tentei refazer mas sempre dá o mesmo erro.

```
public class Prova {
    private String titulo;

    private int numQuestoes;

    private String disciplina;

    private double notaMaxima;

    private String professor;

    private int id = 0;

    Questao[] questao = new Questao[100];


    static int contador = 0;


  Prova(String titulo, int numQuestoes , String disciplina , double  notaMaxima , String professor){


    contador++;
    this.id = Prova.contador;

  this.titulo = titulo;
  this.numQuestoes = numQuestoes;
  this.disciplina = disciplina;
  this.notaMaxima = notaMaxima;
  this.professor = professor;
  }

  public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
  }

  public void setTitulo(String titulo){
      this.titulo = titulo;
  }

  public int getNumQuestoes() {
    return numQuestoes;
  }

  public void setNumQuestoes(int numQuestoes) {
    this.numQuestoes = numQuestoes;
  }

  public String getDisciplina() {
    return disciplina;
  }

  public double getNotaMaxima() {
    return notaMaxima;
  }

  public String getProfessor() {
    return professor;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void mostrarProva() {
    System.out.println("ID: "+id);
    System.out.println("Título: "+titulo);
    System.out.println("Número de Questões: "+numQuestoes);
    System.out.println("Disciplina: "+disciplina);
    System.out.println("Nota Máxima: "+notaMaxima);
    System.out.println("Professor: "+professor);



    //System.out.println("\n");
  } 

  public class Questao {
    private int numero;
  //private String item;
    private String enunciado;
    private String resposta;
    static int contador = 0;
    private int id;



    Questao(int numero, String enunciado, String resposta){

    contador++;
    this.id = Questao.contador;

    this.numero = numero;
    this.enunciado = enunciado; 
    this.resposta = resposta;
    }

  public int getNumero(){
    return numero;
  }

  public String getEnunciado(){
    return enunciado;
  }

  public String getResposta() {
    return resposta;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void mostrarQ() {
    System.out.println("ID :"+id);
    System.out.println("Numero : "+numero);
    System.out.println("Enunciado : "+enunciado);
    System.out.println("Resposta : "+resposta);
  }

  }

     public class CadastroDeProvas {

     Prova[] provas = new Prova[100];

     int qtdProvas = 0;
     int qtdQuest = 0;

    void adicionarQuestao (int i, Questao questao){  
         provas[i].questao[qtdQuest] = questao;
          qtdQuest++;
     }

    void imprimir(){ 
      for(int i = 0; i < qtdProvas; i++){
            provas[i].mostrarProva();
      for(int j=0;j < qtdQuest;j++) {
            provas[i].questao[j].mostrarQ();
      }

        }
    }

}
```

O parametro `int i` é a posição do objeto do vetor de `provas[]` que concatenado com o vetor `questao[]` receberá o objeto `questao`.

```
 void imprimir(){ 
    for(int i = 0; i < qtdProvas; i++){
            provas[i].mostrarProva();
    for(int j=0;j < qtdQuest;j++) {
            provas[i].questao[j].mostrarQ();
    }

        }
    }
```

Toda vez que eu executo o código `imprimir()` ele dá erro nesse método, mais especificamente na linha em destaque abaixo:

```
provas[i].questao[j].mostrarQ();
```

```
public class Questao {
    private int numero;
    //private String item;
    private String enunciado;
    private String resposta;
    static int contador = 0;
    private int id;
```

O erro mais especificamente:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at br.ufc.crateus.provas.CadastroDeProvas.imprimir(CadastroDeProvas.java:26)
>     at br.ufc.crateus.provas.Principal.main(Principal.java:92)
> ```

Comment: O que você está tentando fazer? Qual objetivo quer atingir? A pergunta me ficou um pouco confusa e acredito que talvez precise editar sua questão.  Tente dar um espaço entre as classes pra agrupa-las visivelmente. Onde está a classe Questao?

Comment: O programa até agora está fazendo um cadastro de prova e de questão. E o que estou querendo fazer é juntar uma questão a uma determinada prova, ou seja , quando eu imprimir os dados de uma prova, os dados da respectiva questão possam ser mostrados tbm.

Comment: Por exemplo: Eu faço o cadastro de uma prova "p1" e de uma questão "q1". Eu queria que  a "q1" fosse concatenada com "p1", não sei se "concatenar" é  a melhor palavra, mas é mais ou menos isso o que eu tentei fazer no código acima. Porém, se eu cadastro mais de UMA prova e tento concatenar a uma questao, o programa dá erro ao imprimir().

Comment: O que quer dizer com concatenar prova e questão ? Concatenar na programação significa "juntar textos", não objetos.

Comment: Por isso que coloquei entre aspas. Foi só por falta de palavra melhor.

Comment: O que estou realmente querendo fazer está nos comentarios acima.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro, você deve organizar melhor o seu código com identação e nunca esquecer dos modificadores `public` ou `private`, afinal de contas, em quase todos os casos, a visibilidade de pacote não é o que você quer. E quando quiser, é sempre bom colocar um comentário evidenciando-se isso (`/* package */`) para ficar claro que você realmente quer a visibilidade de pacote e não apenas esqueceu-se do modificador de visibilidade, além de dizer em que outra classe e método do mesmo pacote ese método ou construtor deve ser utilizado.

Feito isso, lembre-se que **trabalhar diretamente com arrays é uma tortura.** Prefira utilizar listas, `Map`s ou alguma outra coisa. Em projetos em Java maduros, modernos e bem desenvolvidos, faz pouco sentido utilizar-se arrays diretamente, e quando aparecem, normalmente é para utilizar-se de *varargs*, ou utilizar-se com anotações, ou porque uma determinada API que precisa ser utilizada produz ou consome arrays ou então são arrays de tipos primitivos utilizados que correspondem a dados brutos utilizados em operações de I/O, ou para realizar alguma coisa bem simples para a qual não precisa de muita sofisticação. Fora desses casos, rararamente é boa ideia o uso direto de arrays. E mesmo nesses casos, frequentemente o array é encapsulado em alguma outra classe.

No seu caso, ao usar listas, você não precisará mais se preocupar em saber quantas questões ou quantas provas estão cadastradas, basta ver o tamanho da lista. Além disso, elimina-se a necessidade de verificar se determinadas posições do array são nulas, o que inclusive elimina o `NullPointerException` que você teve. Também elimina-se a necessidade de ficar rastreando-se um monte de contadores malucos e toda a complexidade envolvida nisso.

Noto que você tem um array que se chama `questao`. Ora, se o nome está no singular, não esperaria que isso fosse um array. O nome `questoes` seria muito melhor. Já o nome `provas` está corretamente no plural.

Também é boa ideia acrescentar-se o modificador `final` em campos de objetos que não possam sofrer atribuição depois de concluído o construtor.

Além disso, o uso de variáveis mutáveis com o modificador `static` (variáveis globais) é sempre um anti-padrão. Uma coisa ruim, um sinal de que algo no seu projeto está errado. No seu caso, as variáveis `contador` das classes `Prova` e `Questao` servem para contar as provas e questões, e portanto, faz sentido que estivessem na classe `CadastroDeProvas`. Aliás, no caso de `Questao`, o `id` poderia ser substituído pelo `id` da prova e mais o número da questão na prova.

Por fim, se você quer obter a descrição de um objeto, use o método `toString()`, que inclusive já é implementado de forma satisfatória para listas. Colocar o `System.out.println` diretamente no método de mostrar, impede a você de pegar essa descrição e decidir o que fazer com ela, caso queira colocar em outro lugar. Outra alternativa seria trabalhar-se com `StringBuilder`s.

E para garantir um bom encapsulamento, nunca acesse um campo do tipo array ou lista de outra classe diretamente. Sempre faça isso por meio de um método. E e se método não deve exportar o array ou lista, e sim fazer a operação desejada com ele. Ou seja, ao invés de:

```
provas[i].questao[qtdQuest] = questao;
```

Você faria algo como:

```
provas[i].adicionarQuestao(questao);
```

Entretanto, isso ainda usa `provas` como se fosse um array. Além disso, a resposabilidade de acrescentar-se uma questão na prova deveria estar na classe `Prova`, e não na classe `CadastroDeProvas`.

Dito isso, vamos reestruturar as suas classes:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Prova {
    private final String titulo;

    private final String disciplina;

    private final double notaMaxima;

    private final String professor;

    private final int id;

    private final List<Questao> questoes = new ArrayList<>();

    // Deve ser utilizado apenas pelo método criarProva da classe CadastroDeProvas.
    /* package */ Prova(int id, String titulo, String disciplina, double notaMaxima, String professor) {
        this.id = id;
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.disciplina = disciplina;
        this.notaMaxima = notaMaxima;
        this.professor = professor;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public int getNumeroQuestoes() {
        return questoes.size();
    }

    public String getDisciplina() {
        return disciplina;
    }

    public double getNotaMaxima() {
        return notaMaxima;
    }

    public String getProfessor() {
        return professor;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void adicionarQuestao(String enunciado, String resposta) {
        questoes.add(new Questao(this, questoes.size() + 1, enunciado, resposta);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder("ID: " + id
                + "\nTítulo: " + titulo
                + "\nNúmero de Questões: " + getNumeroQuestoes()
                + "\nDisciplina: " + disciplina
                + "\nNota Máxima: " + notaMaxima
                + "\nProfessor: " + professor
                + "\nQuestões: " + questoes);
    }
}
```

```
public class Questao {
    private final Prova prova;
    private final int numero;
    private final String enunciado;
    private final String resposta;

    // Deve ser utilizado apenas pelo método adicionarQuestao da classe Prova.
    /* package */ Questao(Prova prova, int numero, String enunciado, String resposta) {
        this.prova = prova;
        this.numero = numero;
        this.enunciado = enunciado; 
        this.resposta = resposta;
    }

    public Prova getProva() {
        return prova;
    }

    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public String getEnunciado() {
        return enunciado;
    }

    public String getResposta() {
        return resposta;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ID da prova: " + prova.getId()
                + "\nNúmero: " + numero
                + "\nEnunciado: " + enunciado
                + "\nResposta: " + resposta
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CadastroDeProvas {
     private final List<Prova> provas = new ArrayList<>();

     public Prova criarProva(String titulo, String disciplina, double notaMaxima, String professor) {
         Prova p = new Prova(provas.size() + 1, titulo, disciplina, notaMaxima, professor);
         provas.add(p);
     }

     @Override
     public String toString() { 
         return provas.toString();
     }
}
```

Por fim, a sua classe `Prova` também parece que irá confundir dois conceitos distintos. Um conceito é o modelo da prova, com o enunciado das questões. Outra coisa é a resposta dada por cada aluno na prova que recebeu e a nota obtida. Entretanto, para mudar-se isso eu precisaria saber mais algumas coisas sobre o seu projeto.

Answer (score 0):

Você conseguira resolver melhor utilizando arraylist, se não conhece ainda de uma olhada.

Agora se você estiver fazendo um trabalho para faculdade e/ou curso então.

Primeiramente array não aceita tipos de valores diferentes.
Se você fizer um array para inserir números inteiros, não poderá sucessivamente acrescentar String ou valores do tipo Double.

Answer (score 0):

OK.. Creio que entendi o que você precisa.

Onde você escreveu:

```
void imprimir(){ 
    for(int i = 0; i < qtdProvas; i++){
            provas[i].mostrarProva();
    for(int j=0;j < qtdQuest;j++) {
            provas[i].questao[j].mostrarQ();
    }

        }
    }
```

Você queria dizer... Algo do tipo:

- Prova 1 + dados da prova 1;

  - Prova1.Questao1 + dados da questao 1
  - Prova1.Questao2 + dados da questao 2
  - Prova1.Questao2 + dados da questao 3
  - Prova1.QuestaoN + dados da questao N
- Prova 2  + dados da prova 2;

  - (etc)

Me corrija, se eu estiver errado. Ainda estou tentando descobrir sua necessidade.

Se for isso, faça algo como

```
public class Questao{
//todos os campos da classe + construtores, getters and setters necessarios

@Override
public String toString(){
    return String.format(
  "ID : %s\n"+
  "Numero : %d \n" + 
  "Enunciado : %s \n" +
  "Resposta : %s \n", id, numero, enunciado, resposta );
}

}
```

Agora defina a Prova:

```
public class Prova{
    //todos os campos, construtores, getters e setters

    private List<Questao> questoes = new Arraylist<>();

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String saida = 
            String.format("ID: %d \n" + 
                    "Título: %s \n" + 
                    "Número de Questões: %d \n" +
                    "Disciplina: %s \n" +
                    "Nota Máxima: %f \n" + 
                    "Professor: %s \n",
                    id, numQuestoes, disciplina, notaMaxima, professor 
            );
        for(Questao q : questoes){
            saida += q.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Agora, é só correr pro abraço:

public class CadastroDeProvas {

```
 List<Prova> provas = new Arraylist<>();

 int qtdProvas = 0;
 int qtdQuest = 0;

void adicionarQuestao (int i, Questao questao){  
     provas.getQuestoes.add(questao);
     //será necessário algum ajuste aqui
 }

void imprimir(){ 
   for(Prova p : provas){
        System.out.println(p);
   }
}
```

Implicitamente, o metodo println vai chamar o método toString herdado da classe Object (mãe de todas as classes java) e trará a verbalização que você deseja.

Comment: Cara, era justamente isso msm! Ontem pela manhã um amigo me deu uma força aqui e deu certo , ele mostrou praticamente o que vc fez agora , vlw Carlos !!

Comment: É isso aí, @ÍcaroTimóteo .  É sempre recomendável marcar a sua pergunta como solucionado, quando for o caso. Outras pessoas podem encontrar as perguntas e respostas mais facilmente. Essa é a dinâmica desse fórum.